# Is the lightsaber Dooku uses the same as the one Darth Bane had?

Tags: star-wars, sith, lightsaber

Since Bane introduced the Rule of 2, the Sith sometimes took their late master's lightsaber with them.

Is it possible that count Dooku/Darth Tyranus received Darth Bane's lightsaber, since they are both curved lightsabers?

Comment: I thought Darth Plaegus was Darth Sidious' master (who in turn is Count Dooku's) so wouldn't he be the one to own Darth Bane's lightsaber?

Comment: But wasn't Plaegus death by the time Darth Tyranus was born (as a sith that is)

Comment: Yes, however Sidious (Palpatine) was still alive, still the master, so he would still be in possesion of whatever he took from his master (Plaegus) upon his demise.

Comment: @Monty129 i just found out it isn't the same

Comment: The curved light saber was because Christopher Lee in real life had severe arthuritis and when he got the part of Dokuu he couldn't handle a straight light saber handle.Therefore working with Lucas and his doctor they came up with the curved handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No. Dooku built his own lightsaber.

This is from the [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku%27s_lightsaber):

> When Dooku became a Jedi Master, he constructed a more personalized
> lightsaber that had a curved hilt that allowed for precise movements
> and was designed for a Makashi duelist. It could be shortened with the
> press of a button, allowing for more flexibility in
> lightsaber-to-lightsaber combat. This lightsaber had a blue
> blade, and Dooku wielded it during the Battle of Galidraan.
> Dooku also occasionally carried a more conventional lightsaber as a
> Jedi Master.

Comment: Darth Cognus, Bane's apprentice (and then [his killer's](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Zannah) apprentice), [had it](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane's_lightsaber) after Bane.

Comment: Indeed, but then it becomes a bit foggy on who took what weapon

Answer (score 1):

Possible but unlikely. As the person above me has stated Dooku already saw the advantages of a curved hilt as a Jedi. It is still possible that sidious, after reckognizing his apprentices' affinity to them he passed down Banes Lightsaber. (it's often said that Sidious had dozens of secret locations that he kept for artifacts and special items even before the great purge.